# API Route tripping error handling when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, express

I have an Node/Express API route. It's supposed to return a JSON response with the time stamp and the date after I use the URL to put a timestamp in. For example, http://localhost:3000/1448928000 should respond {"unix" : "1448928000", "naturalFormat" : "12-01-2015"} instead it trips my else statement that is supposed to return the key values paired with null if there was invalid input.

I'm not really sure why this is. I have never used Regex before. Maybe it's my regex?

Any help would be appreciated!

```
router.get('/:unix', function(req, res) {
  var timestamp = req.params.unix;
  var regex = new RegExp("\d{10}");
  if (regex.test(timestamp)) {
    var date = unixToDate(timestamp);
    res.json({ unix : timestamp, naturalFormat : date });
  } else {
    res.json({ unix: null, naturalFormat : null});
  }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that condition `if (regex.test(timestamp))` is met? (and that `timestamp` is really a timestamp)

Comment: I think so... My regex is supposed to equal true if it a 10 digit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash in the regular expression:

```
new RegExp("\\d{10}");
```